# docker hint： Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

When I use command: `docker pull ubuntu:16.04`

I got this error：

```
liudecai@my-ubuntu-server:~$ docker pull ubuntu:16.04
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for FG3K6C3A15800021, not registry-1.docker.io
```

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04，docker version is 17.03.1-ce

docker information：

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me fallow this steps：

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33154

https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

Comment: Please copy concerned content, links can be changed or removed